# type in a Postcode and get the address

Tags: delphi

(I asked this Question in stack**overflow** (Delphi) and they suggested that I try here.

> Is there a site to submit my Delphi 7 coding to?
> Hi I am learning how to build compound components. My latest works fine, but I am wondering if there is a site where I could submit my code and receive feedback.
> I would like this feedback to offer better coding practices with explanations so I can learn

)

I have access to the UK's Royal Postcode Files and use these to help my local Charity's IT dept. I split this file in to over 1,000 files of 30,000 lines each.
In another folder I have A-Z index files. So the B.csv file contains all Postcodes beginning with B. The format of the file is Postcode, File reference ie

```
BA13 3PZ,file46.csv
```

The idea of my component is for the user to type in a Postcode and get the address. My Component searches the 30,000,000 postcodes finds the correct one, the use then picks the correct address and the address is copied to the underlying external database. It works and is fast but as I want to improve I would be grateful for
any feedback good or bad.

```
unit BtnPost;

interface

uses Windows, WinTypes, WinProcs, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Controls,
Forms, Graphics, Extctrls, Eedit, SevenButton, StdCtrls, Dialogs, ESBRtns,
DB, DBCtrls, ABSMain;

type
  TBtnPost = class(TPanel)
   private
    FOnCtrlBtnClick : TNotifyEvent;
    FOnHeightChange : TNotifyEvent;
    FOnAlistClick : TNotifyEvent;
    FFirst : String;
    FPost : string;
    FAddress : TDbMemo;
    FDset : TABSTable;
    FFilesPath : String;
    FIndexPath : String;
    FOnFirstChange : TNotifyEvent;
    FileList : TStringList;
    IndexList : TStringList;
    RawList : TStringList;
    procedure AutoInitialize;
    procedure AutoDestroy;
    function GetFirst : String;
    procedure SetFirst(Value : String);
    function GetPost : String;
    procedure SetPost(Value : String);
    function GetAddress : TDbMemo;
    procedure SetAddress(Value : TDbMemo);
    function GetDset : TABSTable;
    procedure SetDset(Value : TABSTable);
    function GetFilesPath : String;
    procedure SetFilesPath(Value : String);
    function GetIndexPath : String;
    procedure SetIndexPath(Value : String);
    
   protected
    CtrlBtn : TSevenButton;
    Alist : TListbox;
    procedure HeightChange(Sender : TObject); virtual;
    procedure Loaded; override;
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure FirstChange(Sender : TObject); virtual;
    procedure H_CtrlBtnClick(Sender : TObject); virtual;
    procedure H_AlistClick(Sender : TObject); virtual;
    
   public
    procedure ListSort(LBox:TStrings);
    procedure FindPcode(astr:string);
    procedure MakeMemo(Num:integer);
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    
   published
    Aedit : TEedit;
    property Post : string read GetPost write SetPost;
    property Address : TDbMemo read GetAddress write SetAddress;
    property Dset : TABSTable read GetDset write SetDset;
    property OnCtrlBtnClick : TNotifyEvent read FOnCtrlBtnClick write FOnCtrlBtnClick;
    property OnAlistClick : TNotifyEvent read FOnAlistClick write FOnAlistClick;
    property OnHeightChange : TNotifyEvent read FOnHeightChange write FOnHeightChange;
    property OnFirstChange : TNotifyEvent read FOnFirstChange write FOnFirstChange;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnDragDrop;
    property OnEnter;
    property OnExit;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnResize;
    property First : String read GetFirst write SetFirst;
    property FilesPath : String read GetFilesPath write SetFilesPath;
    property IndexPath : String read GetIndexPath write SetIndexPath;

   end;
  
procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TBtnPost]);
end;

procedure TBtnPost.AutoInitialize;
begin
  FileList := TStringList.Create;
  IndexList := TStringList.Create;
  RawList := TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.AutoDestroy;
begin
  Aedit.Free;
  FileList.Free;
  IndexList.Free;
  RawList.Free;
end;

function TBtnPost.GetFilesPath : String;
begin
  Result := FFilesPath;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.SetFilesPath(Value : String);
begin
  FFilesPath := Value;
end;

function TBtnPost.GetIndexPath : String;
begin
  Result := FIndexPath;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.SetIndexPath(Value : String);
begin
  FIndexPath := Value;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.H_CtrlBtnClick(Sender : TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnCtrlBtnClick) then
  FOnCtrlBtnClick(Sender);
  FPost:=Aedit.Text;
  FFirst:=LeftStr(FPost,1);
  SetFirst(FFirst);
  GetPost;
  FindPcode(Post);
  HeightChange(Self);
 invalidate;
end;

function TBtnPost.GetFirst : String;
begin
 Result := FFirst;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.SetFirst(Value : String);
begin
  FFirst := Value;
  FirstChange(self);
end;

function TBtnPost.GetPost : String;
begin
 Result := FPost;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.SetPost(Value : String);
begin
 FPost:= Value;
end;

function TBtnPost.GetAddress : TDbMemo;
begin
 Result := FAddress;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.SetAddress(Value : TDbMemo);
begin
 FAddress:= Value;
end;

function TBtnPost.GetDset : TABSTable;
begin
 Result := FDset;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.SetDset(Value : TABSTable);
begin
 FDset:= Value;
end;


procedure TBtnPost.FirstChange(Sender : TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnFirstChange) then
  FOnFirstChange(Sender);
  if FIndexPath = '' then
    begin
      ShowMessage('No IndexPath. Closing...');
      Exit;
    end
  else
    begin
      IndexList.LoadFromFile(FIndexPath+FFirst+'.csv');
    end;
end;

constructor TBtnPost.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Aedit := TEedit.Create(Self);
  CtrlBtn := TSevenButton.Create(Self);
  Alist := TListBox.Create(Self);
  Alist.Parent := Self;
  Alist.Align:=alBottom;
  Alist.Height:=0;
  Aedit.Parent := Self;
  Aedit.CharCase:=ecUpperCase;
  Aedit.Visible:=True;
  Height:=30;
  BevelOuter:=bvNone;
  Alist.BorderStyle:=bsNone;
  Alist.BevelOuter:=bvNone;
  Alist.BevelInner:=bvNone;
  Alist.ItemHeight := 19;
  Width := 194;
  Caption := '';
  CtrlBtn.Parent:= Self;
  CtrlBtn.Caption:='Search';
  CtrlBtn.Width:= 64;
  CtrlBtn.Top:=1;
  CtrlBtn.OnClick:=H_ctrlbtnclick;
  Alist.OnClick := H_AlistClick;
  CtrlBtn.Left:=127;
  Visible:=True;
  Aedit.TabOrder:=0;
  AutoInitialize;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.HeightChange(Sender : TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnHeightChange) then
  FOnHeightChange(Sender);
  if Height = 300 then
    begin
      Height:=30;
      Alist.height:=0;
    end
  else
    begin
      Height:=300;
      Alist.height:=Height-35
    end;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.H_AlistClick(Sender : TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnAlistClick) then
  FOnAlistClick(Sender);
  MakeMemo(Alist.ItemIndex);
  HeightChange(Self);
end;

destructor TBtnPost.Destroy;
begin
  AutoDestroy;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.Loaded;
begin
  inherited Loaded;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.Paint;
begin
  inherited Paint;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.ListSort(LBox:TStrings);
var
  i,j, k, m, p1: Integer;
  slq:TStringList;
  a, b:string;
  function GetNPos(sStr: string; iNth: integer): integer;
  var
    sTempStr: string;
    iIteration: integer;
    iTempPos: integer;
    iTempResult: integer;
    sSubStr : string;
  begin
    result := 0;
    sSubStr:=',';
    if ((iNth < 1) or (sSubStr = '') or (sStr = '')) then exit;
    iIteration := 0;
    iTempResult := 0;
    sTempStr := sStr;
    while (iIteration < iNth) do
    begin
      iTempPos := Pos(sSubStr, sTempStr);
      if (iTempPos = 0) then exit;
      iTempResult := iTempResult + iTempPos;
      sTempStr := Copy(sStr, iTempResult + 1, Length(sStr) - iTempResult);
    inc(iIteration);
    end;
    result := iTempResult;
  end;
    function GetNum ( sChaine: String ): Integer ;
    var
      i: Integer ;
      s:string;
    begin
      Result := 0 ;
      for i := 1 to length( sChaine ) do
        begin
          if sChaine[ i ] in ['0'..'9'] then
          s:=s + sChaine[ i ] ;
        end;
      Result:=StrToInt(s);
    end ;
begin
  slq:=TStringList.Create;  
  try
    slq.Sorted:=True;
    for k := LBox.Count-1 downto 0 do
      begin
        p1:=GetNPos(LBox[k],1);// GetNPos function adapted from Sam's(StackOverFlow) GetPositionofNthOccurence
        a:=LeftStr(LBox[k],1); //ESBRtns - left string up to 1st character
        b:=Copy(LBox[k],p1+1,1);
        if ((a[1] in ['A'..'Z']) or (b[1] in ['A'..'Z'])) then
          begin
            slq.Add(LBox[k]);
            LBox.Delete(k);
          end;
      end;
    for i:=0 to LBox.Count-1 do
    for j:=i+1 to LBox.Count-1 do
      begin
        if GetNum(LBox[i]) > GetNum(LBox[j]) then
          begin
            LBox.Exchange(i,j);
          end;
      end;
    LBox.Text:=slq.Text+LBox.Text;
  finally
    slq.free;
  end;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.FindPcode(astr:string);
var
  sl:TStringList;
  slx:TStringList;
  x, y, z, ps, ct:Integer;
  s, t, q:string;
begin
  sl:=TStringList.Create;
  slx:=TStringList.Create;          
    try
      for x:= 0 to IndexList.Count-1 do
        begin
          if astr=LeftTillStr(IndexList[x],',') then sl.add(RightAfterChStr(IndexList[x],','));
        end;
    if sl.Count= 0 then
        begin
          ShowMessage('Postcode not found');
          Aedit.clear;
          Aedit.SetFocus;
          Exit;
        end;
    for y := 0 to sl.Count-1 do
      begin
        FileList.Clear;
        FileList.LoadFromFile(FilesPath+sl[y]);
        for z := 0 to FileList.Count-1 do
          begin
            if Pos(astr,FileList[z])>0 then slx.Add(FileList[z]);
          end;
      end;
    ListSort(slx);
    RawList.Clear;
    RawList.Text:=slx.Text;
    for x:= 0 to slx.Count-1 do
      begin
        s:=slx[x];
        ct:=0; q:='';
        repeat
          ps:=Pos(',',s);
          t:=LeftStr(s,ps-1);
          if ((t<>'') and (t<>' ')) then
            begin
              q:=q+t+' ';
              ct:=ct+1;
            end;
          Delete(s,1,ps);
        until ((ct=3) or (Length(s)<=1));
      alist.Items.Add(q);
    end;
    finally
      sl.Free;
      slx.Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TBtnPost.MakeMemo(Num:integer);
var
  s, w, z, Aline:string;
  sl:TStringList;
  x, acol, ps:Integer;
begin
  sl:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    s:=RawList[num];
    Aline:=s;
    sl.Text:=StringReplace(s,',',#13#10,[rfReplaceAll]);
    x:=0;
    for x := sl.count - 1 downto 0 do
      begin
        if Trim(sl[x]) = '' then
        sl.Delete(x);
      end;
    x:=0;
      repeat
        if Length(sl[x])<7 then
          begin
          sl[x]:=sl[x]+' '+sl[x+1];
            sl.Delete(x+1);;
            end;
          x:=x+1;
      until x=sl.Count-1;
    dset.Close;
    dset.EmptyTable;
    dset.Open;
    acol:=0;
    dset.Insert;
    dset.Edit;
    w:=Aline+',';
      repeat
          ps:=Pos(',',w);
          z:='';
          z:=LeftStr(w,ps-1);
          dset.Fields[acol].AsString:=z;
          Delete(w,1,ps);
          acol:=acol+1;
      until ((Length(w)<=1) or (acol=9));
    FAddress.Text:=sl.Text;
    SetAddress(FAddress);
    dset.Edit;
    dset.Post;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
end.
```